# Cannot launch node

Tags: ros, roslaunch, node

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello!

I have a problem when I launch the ar_kinect.launch file.

I programmed a Phyton code an wrote this line into the ar_kinect.launch:

The ar_kinect.py file is stored in the bin file.

When I execute the launch file I get the following error message:

Error: cannot launch node of type [ar_kinect/ar_kinect.py]: Cannot locate node of type [ar_kinect.py] in package [ar_kinect]

What can I do?

Thanks for help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/50206/cannot-launch-node/) by [JaRu](https://answers.ros.org/users/3620/jaru/) on ROS Answers with karma: 153 on 2012-12-11

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [thebyohazard](https://answers.ros.org/users/1483/thebyohazard/) on 2012-12-11**:
Are you sure the python node you wrote is executable and has the right permissions? The [tutorial on subscribing and publishing](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber%28python%29) explains how to make your script executable.

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-12-11**:
@tbh, I guess you should convert your comment to an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Perhaps the python node you wrote isn't executable or doesn't have the right permissions. The [tutorial on subscribing](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber%28python%29) and publishing explains how to make your script executable.

Change permissions of the file with

`$ chmod +x ar_kinect.py`

and make sure you have the line

`#!/usr/bin/env python`

at the top of your python file.

---

Originally posted by [thebyohazard](https://answers.ros.org/users/1483/thebyohazard/) with karma: 3562 on 2012-12-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [JaRu](https://answers.ros.org/users/3620/jaru/) on 2012-12-12**:
It works. Thanks!